# Django how to handle exception (0, '') while executing sql

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
settings.py:

import configparser
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/home/forge/django_application/config.ini')
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config['mysqlDB']['database'],
        'USER': config['mysqlDB']['user'],
        'PASSWORD': config['mysqlDB']['password'],
        'HOST': config['mysqlDB']['host'],
        'PORT': '3306',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE' : 200,
      
    }
}

__init__.py
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

views.py:
cursor = ""
def index(request):
    email_content = ""
    global cursor
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        for key, value in request.POST.items():
            if key == "body-html":
                email_html_content = value
```

While I running there is coming exception at the server (0, ''). Is there any solution to fix the mysql exception which handle multiple script.

Comment: can you add the whole traceback?